# Having some problems with strcmp() - code compiles but doesn't seem to work

Tags: c, string, character, strcmp

I'm trying to get the user to give me an operator (either +,-,/,*). In order to ensure he/she does this, I wrote this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>



int main(void)
{
char operator;

printf("Enter operator: (+, -, *, /) \n");

do { scanf("%c", &operator); }
while ((strcmp(&operator, "+") != 0) || (strcmp(&operator, "-") != 0) || (strcmp(&operator, "*") != 0) || (strcmp(&operator, "/") != 0));
}
```

What ends up happening is the loop goes on and on, even if I enter the correct operator. Any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

Edit: (Fixed code)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>



int main(void)
{
char operator;

printf("Enter operator: (+, -, *, /) \n");

    do { scanf(" %c", &operator); }
 while ((strcmp(&operator, "+") != 0) && (strcmp(&operator, "-") != 0) && (strcmp(&operator, "*") != 0) && (strcmp(&operator, "/") != 0));

}
```

Comment: `strcmp` takes a zero-terminated string, not a character. It could be as simple as `if(operator == '+')`

Comment: @WeatherVane, your comment is worth converting to an answer.

Comment: I think we can also take advantage of the fact that the internal representation of `char` is of type integer, the comparison thus can be simplified to check against values like this `operator != 42`

Comment: @ImranAli please don't use magic numbers when you mean `'*'` (an `int` type). Not only is the symbol easier to read, there is no guarantee that it has the numeric value `42`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `strcmp` takes a zero-terminated string, not a character. For that reason, use of

```
strcmp(&operator, "+")
```

is cause for undefined behavior.

Your code could be as simple as

```
while ((operator != '+') && ...)
```

Notice I also changed the `||` to `&&`.

You also will need a space before `"%c"` like this `" %c"` so that if the input loop repeats, it clears off any `newline` that was left in the input buffer.

EDIT: You don't seem to have made the right correction, I suggest

```
do {
    scanf(" %c", &operator);
} while (operator != '+' && operator != '-' && operator != '*' && operator != '/');
```

Comment: Yep that definitely worked. Why is it that the && worked and not the || ?

Comment: Because using `||` says the loop will repeat if operator is not equal to any one of those symbols, and it can only be equal to one of them!

Comment: @ManuelStoilov you edited your question, not quite the solution - see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variable operator the following way

```
char operator[2] = { '\0' };
```

And use it like

```
do { scanf("%c ", operator); }
while ((strcmp( operator, "+") != 0) && (strcmp(operator, "-") != 0) && (strcmp(operator, "*") != 0) && (strcmp(operator, "/") != 0));
}
```

Take into account that instead of using numerous `strcmp` you could use one function `strchr`

Comment: That will work but it seems almost deliberately obfuscated. The comparison `operator == '+'` is more readable, more efficient, and less bother. (You could mention the use of `strchr` to do all the comparisons with a single library function.)

Comment: @rici Nothinh prevent you to use comparison like operator[0] == '+'. Moreover I pointed out that it is better to use standard function strchr instead of the numerous comparisons. I showed how correctly to use strcmp.